# Selenium java not get hardcore detected by google recaptcha

Tags: java, selenium, recaptcha

Some websites have a "protected" by google recaptcha thing, and it will check the user before letting them use select features of the website. However where this thing fails, is that it won't allow you to fill out recaptcha to prove you are human. It will just deny you access whenever the google recaptcha is suspicious of you. I also noticed that if I go and find a google recaptcha to solve, with the selenium automation extension, it will be literally impossible to solve it, even if the answers are correct 100% of the time. It will give you the hardest level difficulty recaptcha to solve, and every time you solve one, it will just give you another one. I did ten in a row and it still did not let me solve the recaptcha. So how do I use selenium in a testing environment with recaptcha without having back end access to the website I am testing.

I know one person is going to say "CAPTCHA, an acronym for "Completely Automated Turing Test to tell Computers and Humans Apart"." and you are dumb for asking this question, just give up. So if you are going to say that, please move on to the next question.

Comment: I was going to explain why what you are trying to do *shouldn't* be possible.  But, based on what you said in the last paragraph, I guess you are smart enough to already know that.  So, I will take your advice :-)

Comment: I guess the question should have been, how do you make selenium stealth? And it's something that should be possible. Seems like there is back end software out there specifically looking for selenium itself. It shouldn't be impossible to modify selenium to not trigger detection.

Comment: I had same problem in the past. Only solution was to ask developers to create a backdoor - access without captcha verification. And I'm moving to the next question.

Comment: I am seeing a solution but it's mostly being used for linux. There is some kind of var key = '$cdc_asdjflasutopfhvcZLmcfl_'; that is being broadcasted by chromedriver. If you change this key chromedriver is no longer being detected, but i'm not sure how to do that on windows. I think you can change it by downloading chromedriver source code and compiling it yourself.